# is H2O in gas form in poly styrene combustion?

Tags: combustion

original question:
if we burn 390g of poly styrene (STP), how much gas produces?

**me:** 1008L

**my teacher:** 672L

he says h2o is not in gas form!(because of STP)
who is wrong?

Comment: Neither of you is correct. The problem is indeterminate assuming that after the reaction the system was brought back to STP because the initial volume of the gas was not specified. If say initially a million liters of oxygen was used then all the water would be present as the vapor. However if a stoichiometric amount of oxygen was used then most, but not all, of the water would be in liquid form

Comment: You can't burn polystyrene at STP. You didn't state the entire problem so the final conditions are a bit of a mystery too. But it would seem that the system (products after combustion) was brought back to STP after the reaction.

Comment: @MaxW why we can't burn?

Comment: You can't burn polystyrene at STP. i.e. constantly at $\pu{O ^\circ C}$. When you burn polystyrene it gets hot. So you then have to cool the products down.

Comment: @MaxW so we couldn't burn things while we are near sea and temp is O°C?

Comment: Find a walk in freezer. Strike a match and hold it in your fingers till it burns completely. Did the burning match stay at $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of you is correct. The problem is indeterminate assuming that after the reaction the system was brought back to STP because the initial volume of the gas was not specified. If say initially a million liters of oxygen was used then all the water would be present as the vapor. However if a stoichiometric amount of oxygen was used then most, but not all, of the water would be in liquid form

$$\ce{\pu{M.W. }\ C8H8 = \pu{104.15 g/mol}}\tag{1}$$

$$\ce{\pu{mol }\ C8H8 =\dfrac{\pu{390 g}}{\pu{104.15 g/mol}}} = \pu{3.7446 mol} \tag{2}$$

$$\ce{C8H8 ->[O2] 8CO2 + 4H2O}\tag{3}$$

1.000 mole of a gas at STP ( $\pu{0 °C}$ and $\pu{100 kPa}$) has a volume of $\pu{22.711 L/mol}$.

Let's suppose that a huge excess of oxygen gas was used for the combustion. After the combustion the system is brought back to STP, and all the water is present as vapor. So the upper limit of the gaseous products is:

$$V_\mathrm{gas, UL} =3.7446 \times 12\times 22.711 = \pu{1020.52 L} \ce{->[round to 3] \pu{1.20\times 10^3 L}}\tag{4}$$

Now suppose that a stoichometric amount of oxygen gas was used for the combustion. After the combustion the system is brought back to STP, and some of the water is present as vapor, but most is present as the liquid. The vapor pressure of water at $\pu{0 °C}$ is $\pu{0.6113 kPa}$. So the lower limit of the gaseous products is:

\begin{align}
V_\mathrm{gas, LL} &= (3.7446 \times 8\times 22.711) \times \left(\dfrac{\pu{100 kPa}}{\pu{100 kPa} - \pu{0.6113 kPa}}\right) \\
&= (680.35)\times (1.00615) = \pu{684.53 L} \ce{->[round to 3]} \pu{685 L}\\
\end{align}

**Old definition of STP**

Before 1983 the definition of STP was $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$ and $\pu{101.325 kPa}$ for which 1.000 mole of a gas has a volume of 22.414 L/mol. Using the old value:

$$V_\mathrm{gas, UL} = \dfrac{22.414}{22.711}\times \pu{1020.52 L}= \pu{1007 L}$$

$$V_\mathrm{gas, LL} = \dfrac{22.414}{22.711}\times \pu{684.53 L}= \pu{676 L}$$

---

**The OP finally made me realize that the above answer for $V_\mathrm{gas, LL}$ was not correct for the old STP.**

The problem lies with the fact that the pressure correction for the vapor pressure of water involves subtraction and not just multiplication. As the OP points out:

$$\dfrac{\pu{100 kPa}}{\pu{100 kPa} - \pu{0.6113 kPa}} \ne \dfrac{\pu{101.325 kPa}}{\pu{101.325 kPa} - \pu{0.6113 kPa}}$$

So my calculation yielded

$$V_\mathrm{gas, LL} = \dfrac{22.414}{22.711}\times \pu{684.53 L}= 675.58 \ce{->[Round(3)]}\pu{676 L}$$

But the correct calculation is:

\begin{align}
V_\mathrm{gas, LL} &= (3.7446 \times 8\times 22.414) \times \left(\dfrac{\pu{101.325 kPa}}{\pu{101.325 kPa} - \pu{0.6113 kPa}}\right) \\
&= (671.45)\times (1.00607) = \pu{675.52 L} \ce{->[round to 3]} \pu{676 L}\\
\end{align}

Comment: could you explain about 100kPa/(100kPa - 0.6113kPa) ?

Comment: @aStudent - The current specification for STP defines the pressure as 100 kPa. If a stoichiometric amount of oxygen was used then the gas would contain $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. at $0 ^\circ \mathrm{C}$ the vapor pressure of water alone is  0.6113kPa. The vapor pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ alone would be $\pu{100kPa - 0.6113kPa}$.

Comment: oh excuse me! i made a small mistake. i will delete my comment and i will tell you after checking.

Comment: Let's get back to basics. Was the volume of the products measured at STP, ($\pu{0 ^\circ C}$ and  $\ce{100 kPa}$) or not? If not what T and P?

Comment: now I understood. thank you a lot! PS: in Iran, at least in schools we are using old definition of STP. (you should also consider this at the end. I will edit it)

Comment: I DID consider an older value of STP at the end.

Comment: you did this at original formula -> *100kPa/(100kPa - 0.6113kPa) so at the end you should also do this: * ((100kPa - 0.6113kPa)/100kPa) * (101.325kPa/(101.325kPa - 0.6113kPa)

Comment: Did I get the wrong answer? The point is to do simple calculations not something complicated that is hard to follow.

Comment: you did this : **(3.7446×8×22.711)×(100 kPa/(100 kPa−0.6113 kPa))** in old STP we have 22.414 L/mol **and 101.325 kPa** you only considered 22.414 L/mol.

Comment: I don't know why I did the calc that way. It just seemed the right way at the time. Note that it is just a pressure correction: $$\dfrac{100}{101.325} = \dfrac{22.414}{22.711}$$

Comment: we should do three corrections : (3.7446×8× **22.414** )×( **100 kPa** /( **100 kPa** −0.6113 kPa)) .(we should also change _pressure of CO2 and total gases_) i.e. : ( **100 kPa** /( **100 kPa** −0.6113 kPa)) does not exactly equal to ( **101.325 kPa** /( **101.325 kPa** −0.6113 kPa))

Comment: Please post your own answer. I'll give you my opinion if it is right or wrong.

Comment: LOL - My high school chemistry class was in 1969. I automatically think of 22.414 liters as being the molar volume at STP. I have to remind myself that the molar volume is now 22.711 at STP. I also think in torr, not kPa. My brain is also wired for calories for heat. There are certain numbers that you will just remember after working a lot of problems.

Comment: :) look at [this](https://prnt.sc/shnse3) picture. if you correct red ones, final answer decreases by 0.05.

Comment: **I finally understand your point. You are correct.**

Comment: we didn't have any pressure correction for the vapor pressure of water! (in your last edit : "... that the pressure correction **for the vapor pressure of water** involves ..." )